# Getting Paths from Config file in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, app-config

I want to be able to change directories that I use for a program (I am moving files from one directory to another and also commiting to SVN).  I want to be able to change the directories relatively quickly, but also, these directories are more or less set.  The directories might changes once or twice every six months or so.  So I don't want to keep throwing it into a command line application, and I also don't want to have to recompile this application everytime I want to change the paths...  How can I use a config file in WPF to get and set the paths to the appropriate files and directories like in an ASP.net application or a WCF service?

Thanks.

Comment: what paths are you talking about? Paths for the project items or some external (data etc.) ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this ... 
In you app.config change your appsetting to

```
<applicationSettings>
    <WpfApplication1.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="appsetting" serializeAs="String">
            <value>c:\testdata.xml</value>
        </setting>
    </WpfApplication1.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

Then in code-behind

```
string xmlDataDirectory = WpfApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.appsetting.ToString()
```

Comment: precisely what I was thinking.

Comment: wait, do WPF projects have app.configs?  I was using the App.xaml

Comment: Nope... I see a App.xaml  This isn't a website or service, this is a WPF application.  I don't even hook into a service, so there would be no app.config for that either?  I could probably add a text file and just read that in.  But That seems like such a clunky thing to do.

Comment: you could still utilize a Config file via the ConfigurationManager it's your choice..

Comment: WPF apps have app configs.  Go to Properties and double click Settings.settings and start entering the material.  An app.config will appear...